# How to delete database documents when cookie expires

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

what I am trying to achieve is, that when the cookie expires it deletes the document  in the collection Orders using mongoose, I have already set up the expiration for the cookie.

And tried to use if statements  in an app.use but it does not work, an example like if (req.session.cookie._expires == new Date()) { and have tried to set the new Date to a variable but still unsuccessful.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "Our little secret.",
    resave: false,
    saveUnitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge : 36000 }
}));




app.use(function(req, res, next) {

      const session = req.session.cookie;

      const day = new Date();

      if (session && new Date(session._expires) === new Date()) {
           Order.deleteMany({}, function(req, res) {
             console.log("Order deleted");
           });
      }
    next();
 });
```

Thank´s in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

var session = req.session.cookie || '';
  if (new Date(session._expires) < new Date()) {
         Order.deleteMany({}, function(req, res) {
      console.log("Order deleted");
 });
        console.log('User session has expired.');
        req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + 36000)
 }

 console.log(req.session);

 next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects are comparing by links. You create two different objects with different links. Here get always false:

`new Date(session._expires) === new Date()`

Comparison of timestamps should work:

`+new Date(session._expires) <= +new Date()`

Comment: What includes `session` and `session._expires`?
What is result of:
`console.log(session && +new Date(session._expires) <= +new Date());`

Comment: When I console log it return false

Comment: thanks for the help, but I figure it out, you can check, the answer. first declare a variable for the cookie and check if does not has a cookie, then compare to the date and if it already expires, reseted, if you need to reset of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Moment npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) to compare dates.

Try this :

```
if (session && moment(session._expires)startOf('day') === moment().startOf('day')) {
       Order.deleteMany({}, function(req, res) {
         console.log("Order deleted");
       });
  }
```